# change border color of imagebutton used inside a repeater on mouse click

Tags: asp.net

I have a repeater and there is an imagebutton inside that. what I need is to change the border color of the ImageButton when user clicks on that. 
I have searched lots of sites but unfortunately have not found any solution. I even changed the imagebutton to an image which is inside an anchor but it didn't work too.
I tried to change the border color through javascript for the onclick event of imagebutton,but still unsucessful. I have also tried linkbutton instead of image button.
Unfortunately I can not use updatepanel in this project .
Any solution would be highly appreciated.

CSS:

```
.HighlightBorder{border:3px solid pink;}


 <asp:Repeater ID="rptrPlatforms" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptrPlatforms_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptrPlatforms_ItemCommand">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <panel style="border: 4px solid green; height: 250px; width: 330px;" runat="server">
              <asp:ImageButton ID="imgPlatform" alt="" Style="border: 4px solid; height: 240px; width: 320px;" runat="server" OnCommand="Platform_Click" CommandName="PlatformClick" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PlatformLanguageID")+","+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PlatformID") %>' />
         </panel>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void rptrPlatforms_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton img = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl(e.CommandName);

        if (e.CommandName == ClickedElementID.Text && img != null)
        {
            img.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("bordercolor", "00FF00");
            img.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("borderStyle", "solid");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The ID of your ImageButton is "imgPlatform" but you are using the `CommandName` to find the control, which is "PlatformClick". `RepeaterCommandEventArgs` comes with a nice property called `CommandSource` which would be the source of the command.

Comment: @j.f Thank you for your comment, please let me know how i can check the id of the clicked imagebutton as they must be the same when using repeater?

Comment: When you click your ImageButton, does `rptrPlatforms_ItemCommand` fire? Does a breakpoint hit if you place one in that event?

Comment: Yes , I also used CommandSource as you correctly recommended and I expected to see all the imagebuttons with the same ID with new border color at this stage, but unfortunately it doesn't change the border color yet. this is my latest changes:`code`   var ImageID = ((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).ID;
            ImageButton img = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl(ImageID);
            img.Attributes["CssClass"] = "HighlightBorder";

Comment: Check out my answer below. I think that should help.

Comment: Make sure to mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem or add more explanation if it didn't. This will help future readers. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @j.f, Thanks a lot J,F, Its working now perfectly, Unfortunately as I am new here and I still don't have enough reputation, I can not mark the answers as useful.

Comment: You're welcome - glad I could help! Not a problem. Keep at it and you'll give there eventually!

Comment: Dear J.F, I have another problem that is detecting the id of the selected imagebutton in order to unhighlight the previous button when clicking on another one, it may be related to this question but I open a new question in order to have this one answered.Please help me in that one too.

Comment: Yep, just write up a new question and hopefully someone can help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageButtons by default come with `style="border-width: 0"`. I presume this is so it doesn't clash with the images being presented. So if you want a width, make sure you give it a width. By rules of CSS, since your new width is added after the pre-existing width, your new width is honored instead.

```
img.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("border-color", "#00FF00");
img.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("border-width", "1px");
img.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("border-style", "solid");
```

Or you can use the `BorderWidth` property of the ImageButton which will replace the pre-existing width value with your new one.

```
img.BorderColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#00FF00");
img.BorderWidth = 1;
```

You are also doing more work than you need to. `RepeaterCommandEventArgs` comes with a CommandSource property. The value of this property is the source of the command (i.e. your ImageButton).

```
protected void rptrPlatforms_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton img = (ImageButton)e.CommandSource;

    // ...
}
```

But remember that since this is the `ItemCommand` event for your entire Repeater, it is possible that the source may not be an ImageButton in the future. This would cause issues with this casting.

Answer (score 1):

can you please try just that

```
protected void rptrPlatforms_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
        ImageButton img = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl(e.CommandName);

        img.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("bordercolor", "00FF00");
        img.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("borderStyle", "solid");

}
```

**Edit**

please try following

```
 protected void rptrPlatforms_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
        ImageButton img = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("imgPlatform");

        img.BorderColor = Color.Red;

}
```

and let me know. 
Thank you

Comment: Thanks Yuri for your reply, Unfortunately it didn't work, I even used "imgPlatform" instead of e.commandName as J.F noted a correct problem and also used border-color instead of bordercolor that was mistyped and even used : img.Attributes["CssClass"] = "HighlightBorder"

Comment: Thanks Yuri for your comments, I tried that but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Yes I even tried the edited one but it didn't work, I even added few more lines to that as below but it had no effect. fortunately the mentioned solution by J.F solved the problem.              ImageButton img2 = (ImageButton)e.CommandSource;
            img2.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Pink;
            img2.BorderWidth = 2;
            img2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;